# Getting absolute URL to page in code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

I am new to ASP.NET and am trying to convert a web application from using hard-coded deployment locations (ie, /base/path/index.aspx) to discovering them at runtime.  If I use `Response.Redirect()`, I can express the path as '~/index.aspx' and, at runtime, ASP.NET will build the correct URL to send the redirect to based on where the web application is deployed.

There are places in the code where Javascript and/or HTML is generated dynamically and sent to the client as part of the response to force a new window.  In these cases, I don't know how to get the actual URL that should be opened in the new window.  Using ~ doesn't work in this case since the URL is being evaluated by the browser and not the server.  Is there a class or method in ASP.NET that will give me the URL I am looking for?  I'd look myself, but I don't even know how to properly phrase my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`VirtualPathUtility` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.virtualpathutility) is what you are looking for.

Specifically you can use these methods:

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~/");
```

Comment: thank you so much. I *always* forget what whas the name of that class

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/path/some_page.aspx") %>';
    window.open(url, 'name');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tilde (~) is basically a shortcut to [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request.ApplicationPath and build your way to the page.